# How does the Wigner function transform when the transformation is provided in $(x,p)$-form?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, quantum-optics, wigner-transform

In quantum optics, when a transformation of canonical variables $\hat{x},\hat{p}$ is provided, how does the Wigner function change under the transformation? For example, when the transformation is
$$
\hat{x}' = G\hat{x} \quad , \quad \hat{p}' = \hat{p}/G
$$
(the squeezing operation), the transformed Wigner function $W'(x,p)$ should be
$$
W'(x,p) = W(x/G,Gp)
$$
where $\hat{x},\hat{p}$ are the original variables and $W$ is the original Winger function. This is a trivial case, but I cannot derive the general transformation rule. For instance, when the photon loss (efficiency=$\eta$)
$$
\hat{x}' = \sqrt{\eta}\hat{x}+\sqrt{1-\eta}\hat{x}_{vac} \quad , \quad \hat{p}' = \sqrt{\eta}\hat{p}+\sqrt{1-\eta}\hat{p}_{vac}
$$
occurs, how is the transformation represented by the Wigner function? How about a case of a measurement-based squeezing gate using a finite squeezed ancilla with the following form?
$$
\hat{x}' = \sqrt{R}\hat{x}+\sqrt{1-R}\hat{x}_{ancilla} \quad , \quad \hat{p}' = \hat{p}/\sqrt{R}
$$
($R$ denotes the reflectivity of the beamsplitter where the input and the ancilla interfere)

Answer (score 1):

If we restrict to specific Hamiltonians which are at most quadratic in the creation\annihilation operators (and that are described by symplectic transformations $\mathbf{S}$ acting on the quadrature vectors - plus eventually a displacement) it's easy to find the corresponding transformation in the Wigner picture.

If we have a transformation of the type
\begin{equation}
\bar{\mathbf{x}} \to \mathbf{S}\bar{\mathbf{x}} + \mathbf{d}\\
\boldsymbol{\sigma} \to \mathbf{S}\boldsymbol{\sigma}\mathbf{S}^T
\end{equation}
where $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$ is the mean value vector and $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is the covariance matrix, the Wigner transforms as
\begin{equation}
W(\mathbf{x})\to W'(\mathbf{x})=W(\mathbf{S}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{d}))
\end{equation}
Note that the quadrature vector is ordered using the convention $\mathbf{x}=(\mathbf{q}_1, \mathbf{q}_2,\dots, \mathbf{p}_1, \mathbf{p}_2\dots)$. You can find this transformation and other details on Wigner and characteristic function in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0503237.pdf). Another good reference is "Measuring the Quantum state of light" by Ulf Leonhardt.

I'm not aware of a general rule like this one for general non-gaussian transformations but maybe someone more expert than me will aswer later with more details. At some point I had to derive the Wigner function of a photon-subtracted state and I had to use directly the definition of the Wigner function with the $\hat{\rho}$ operator.

For the specific problems that you stated, you can check the step by step calculations in Sec. 4.1.4 "Beam splitter model of absorption" in Leonhardt book.